# I have a column with many null values and i want to replace them with values from the same column based on a condidtion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table one is "profiles" in which I have two columns "user_id" and "interest" and table two "friends" in which I have two columns basically a foreign-keys on "profiles" table "user_id"and "friend_id". Now i have many missing values in "interest" column which i want to update with interests of friends. Please help

[image: profiles table]

[image: friends table]

Comment: Seems a weird requirement, my friends interests are not my interests.

Comment: Please don't post links to images for data. Post data as **formatted** `text`. Images aren't helpful to the volunteers you're asking help from as the only way they can use it is to transcribe it. Please take the time to provide your samples in a consumable format. Could you also show us what you've tried so far to to solve this problem? I also agree with @HoneyBadger, I don't share all my interests with my friends, and neither do they with me. Also, wouldn't that (eventually) mean that everyone has an interest in everything; apart from those with no friends?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store valued calculated from table data. Data redundancy and risk of data inconsistency. If you really want those friends' values, create a view instead.

Comment: I have a special situation and i need this to be done as required

Comment: Also the question could be defined in better way - for example what if a user X has null 'interests' and 50 friends each with some unique interest -> does that mean that user X will be update with 50 interests, or you want to assign him only a few, or even only one top based on some criteria ?

Comment: Only one from friends interests , i only need to remove null values

Comment: It looks like the data is being stored as a string, not in a "Normal Form" way.  There isn't any easy SQL solution outside of a complex algorithm.  A general rule of data-basing is that data inside a column should be atomic, and not require subdividing in order to make sense of it.  Also allowing free-text such as multiple periods ... or smiley faces :) isn't making this any easier in terms of selecting distinct values.

Comment: This is still not clear. Can there be multiple rows per user in the first table? Or does each user only have one interest? Does it make a difference in the friendship table, if the users are swapped, i.e. is `(1,2)`= `(2,1)`? And if there is a row with a  null interest, we take all the interests of that user's friends and pick one of these interests arbitrarily?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to populate the null values using the SQL below or similar:

```sql
update p
set p.interest = f.interest
FROM profiles p
join (
    select top 1 pp.user_id, ff.interest
    from profiles pp
    join friends ff on pp.user_id = ff.friend_id
    where ff.interest is not null
) f ON p.user_id = f.user_id
where p.interest is null
```